# Group Dictionary values of a particular key

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have a Dictionary of String and a list of type variable. i.e.

```
Dim search As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of TypeResult))
```

My query is if I get 3 key-value pairs inside the dictionary and I want to groupby the values of only a particular key (say key no. 3), then how to do the same.

By groupby I want to eliminate any duplicate values coming in the List of a particular key.

Any code snippets or suggestions would be great.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: If it is a Dictionary, the keys are unique, so they will all be groups of one.

Comment: So your question is how to group by a list, the dictionary is irrelevant to the question as it's keys are unique, as Plutonix wrote. **Edit** Now that I've read your question agian, I think you probably need `distinct`, not `groupby`

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: I am saying I want the values coming with a particular key to be unique. The keys agreed will be unique. But the values coming in the List might have duplicate values. So want to eliminate any duplicate values coming in the List.

Comment: @ one site I saw a groupby being used for a dictionary
Dim duplicates = list.GroupBy(Function(x) x).Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).Select(Function(x) x.Key)
But my confusion was how to pass the key string.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to eliminate any duplicate values coming in the List of a particular key

There are a few ways to do this, depending on *how* and *when* you add items to the list for a particular key and at what time you need them to be without duplicates.

You could do it like this, to ensure that there are never any duplicate values in the list.

```
Sub AddItem(ByVal key As String, ByVal val as TypeResult)
    Dim values As List(Of TypeResult)
    If (search.TryGetValue(key, values)) Then
        If (Not values.Contains(val)) Then
            values.Add(val)
        End If
    Else
        values = new List(Of TypeResult)()
        values.Add(val)
        search.Add(key, values)
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `TypeResult` must provide an `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementation, otherwise the call to `Contains` may not provide you with the desired behavior.

Another option is to filter out duplicate values when they are being returned to someone asking for the values of a specific key.

```
Function DistinctValuesFor(ByVal key As String) As IEnumerable(Of TypeResult)
    Dim values As List(Of TypeResult)
    If (search.TryGetValue(key, values)) Then
        DistinctValuesFor = values.Distinct()
    Else
        DistinctValuesFor = Enumerable.Empty(Of TypeResult)()
    End If
End Function
```